# C++ Separate a string by spaces and commas

Tags: c++, file, vector, file-io

I am trying to read in a text file, separate the integer values by commas and white spaces " ," and add each individual integer excluding " ," to a vector of integers. The following code only prints the first value. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
std::vector<int> vecOfStrs;
std::ifstream fileIn("Scores.txt");
std::string str;

while (std::getline(fileIn, str)) {
    if (str.size() > 0) { //If there is any string at all do...

        std::stringstream ss(str); //std operator that turns str string into a stringstream to be operated on
        for (int i; ss >> i;) {
            vecOfStrs.push_back(i);
            if (ss.peek() == ' ,')
                ss.ignore();
        }
    }
}

fileIn.close();

for (size_t i = 0; i < vecOfStrs.size(); i++) {
    std::cout << vecOfStrs[i] ;
}

return 0;
}
```

And here is the text file "scores.txt" ::

```
76, 89, 150, 135, 200, 76, 12, 100, 150, 28, 178, 189, 167, 200, 175, 150, 87, 99, 129, 149, 176, 
200, 87, 35, 157, 189
```

Comment: Side note: Single quotes denote a character. `' ,'` tries to stuff 2 characters into a single character. The results of this are somewhat odd. Most compilers will give a warning. Don't ignore the warnings. They are the first line of defense against logic errors.

Comment: You could have done just a `std::replace` of all commas with a space, and then use `std::istringstream` without all of those `peek` calls.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out if anyone happens upon this looking for an answer. Use

```
if (ss.peek() == ',' || ss.peek() == ' ')
```

to check if it is a white space or a comma instead of

```
if (ss.peek() == ' ,')
```

Comment: This isn't quite a complete solution. This code alone will detect the space in the input stream and ignore it. This leaves the comma in the input stream to be picked up by `ss >> i`, and `ss >> i` cannot parse a comma. It needs to be wrapped in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Change your for loop to this and it'll work! Tested it on my side with the rest of your code.

```
for(string i; ss >> i;)//treat as string for string manipulation
{
    size_t pos=str.find(',');  //look for a comma
    if(pos!=std::string::npos) i.erase(pos); //if comma is found, erase it!
    vecOfStrs.push_back(stoi(i));  //convert string to integer
}
```

Basically: read it as a string, [find()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) and [erase()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/) what you don't want and then use that as input.

One problem that I found in your code is that you were peeking for 2 characters. You should only peek for 1 character (see [std::istream::peek](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/peek/?kw=peek)). I assume that's what caused unexpected behaviour.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to resort to `peek()` and `ignore()`.

You could simply replace all commas with a space, and then use `std::istringstream.`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
   std::vector<int> vecOfStrs;
   std::string str = "76, 89, 150, 135, 200, 76, 12, 100, 150, 28, 178, 189, 167, 200,"
                      "175, 150, 87, 99, 129, 149, 176, 200, 87, 35, 157, 189";

   // replace all commas with a space
   std::replace(str.begin(), str.end(), ',', ' ');                      

   std::stringstream ss(str); 
   for (int i; ss >> i;) 
       vecOfStrs.push_back(i);

   // output results
   for (size_t i = 0; i < vecOfStrs.size(); i++) 
       std::cout << vecOfStrs[i] << "\n" ;
}
```

[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/34c23aa5a5fd916a)

Answer (score 0):

This should work. It parses the file line by line, matching all of the required strings then converting them to an int while adding them to the `std::vector`.

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <vector

   int main()
    {
        std::ifstream fileIn("Scores.txt")
        std::string str;
        std::regex words_regex("[^, ]+");
        std::vector<int> vecOfStrs();

        while (std::getline(fileIn, str)) 
         {
            if (str.size() > 0) 
           {
              auto words_begin = std::sregex_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), words_regex);
              auto words_end = std::sregex_iterator() 
              for (std::sregex_iterator i = words_begin; i != words_end; ++i)                             
                 vecOfStrs.emplace_back(std::stoi(*i.str())); 

           }   
       }

    }
```